# Bootstrap 5 style is applied to FullCalendar v5 and Angular 8

Tags: css, angular8, fullcalendar-5

I have created calendar in Angular 8 using FullCalendar v5. Without any styling the calendar looks good.
Now I want to add forms to create event on date click, and hence I'm using Bootstrap v5. In angular.json file, I have added the required imports to use Bootstrap v5
[as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRY3l.png).
I can add events to calendar using Bootstrap form, however now  the bootstrap style is being applied to the calendar, which I don't want [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLd70.png). As you can see in the image the calendar day names and dates have blue color and underline, which I don't need, instead it should be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPGPh.png).
I tried adding css to calendar classes like

```
a .fc-col-header-cell-cushion {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

but the styles are not being applied to calendar.
How can I remove/not apply bootstrap styling to calendar?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran up against this under slightly different circumstances but was able to correct the underlying issue. The documentation that is most useful is here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/css-customizationCSS and by using Chrome Dev Tools (Tutorial here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/) you can inspect the elements on your calendar. Then you update your css with the following items:

```
/* Removes Default Link formatting from Full Calendar*/
a.fc-daygrid-day-number{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.fc-col-header-cell-cushion{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```